# XML Android Permissions List Full

Tags: android, xml, permissions

I wish I could find this list before I made it. If for some strange reason you also need this, it is here for you. Only because I care. Now, like never before, give your apps full power.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BRICK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DIAGNOSTIC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DUMP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FACTORY_TEST" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_BACK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_APP_TOKENS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MASTER_CLEAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INPUT_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALWAYS_FINISH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ORIENTATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_POINTER_SPEED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SIGNAL_PERSISTENT_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_READ" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_WRITE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
```

### EDITS

Sorry for editing your post, but anything else is blocked (nothing like a closed useful thread). Anyway, few missed permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_TEXT_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERSISTENT_ACTIVITY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SOCIAL_STREAM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_PROFILE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SOCIAL_STREAM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
```

*macias*

Comment: also here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: Not intended to be used as reference, but for copy-n-pasting. You know, if you ever needed every single standard permission in your app. Like I did, just now.

Comment: If I were a user, I would be .. Um .. hesitant to install your app.

Comment: And miss out on one mind-blowing experience?! Your loss, I guess.

Comment: It is great to use stackoverflow as a medium to share information. But try to respect the question answer style. Say ask a question like: what are all possible permissions in android and then answer your question with the list. This enables us to comment, and vote on the whole thing in the regular way.

Comment: Unless you are trying to hide what a virus app will do, or being lazy, there is NO reason to need all the permissions set. And your app will just end up looking like a huge security risk. Permissions exist for a reason. Nice list though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Is this the whole list of available permissions? Jesus!

You could, however, access this list of permissions through using Eclipse, under AndroidManifest.xml by adding a "Uses Permission" control. On the right, it shows you the entire list of available permissions so you don't do a typo somewhere.

But hey, sharing is caring! :D

Comment: I'm not saying you do, :P I'm just saying others might end up adding a "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWOERK_STATE" />" and end up scratching their heads. :P