# Android : How to set all uses-permission?

Tags: android, permissions

How to use all the uses-permission in one single step? Anyone knows this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can find them all here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523075/xml-android-permissions-list-full

Comment: @AlexAdy : It's also very useful. Thank you.

Comment: @Alex Ady : Yes, It's useful for me. Thanks buddy.

Comment: Please don't ever use that list. ever.  Also that list is NOT comprehensive - other applications and services (google services included) expose additional permissions.   In fact, you can make up your own!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In AndroidManifest.xml**, 
Select the **"Permissions"** tab along the bottom of the editor (Manifest - Application - Permissions - Instrumentation - AndroidManifest.xml), then **"Add..."** a **"Uses Permission"** and select the desired permission from the dropdown on the right, or just copy paste in the necessary one (such as the **"android.permission.INTERNET"** permission you required).

For More information, Follow this link:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Answer (score 11):

**All uses permissions in alphabetical order** (updated for API 23)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CONTENT_PROVIDERS_EXTERNALLY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DRM_CERTIFICATES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FM_RADIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_IMS_CALL_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_INPUT_FLINGER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_KEYGUARD_SECURE_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MTP"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_CONDITIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_PDB_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_VOICE_INTERACTION_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIMAX_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ALLOW_ANY_CODEC_FOR_PLAYBACK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ASEC_ACCESS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ASEC_CREATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ASEC_DESTROY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ASEC_MOUNT_UNMOUNT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ASEC_RENAME"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BACKUP"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_CARRIER_MESSAGING_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_CARRIER_SERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_CHOOSER_TARGET_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_CONDITION_PROVIDER_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_CONNECTION_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DIRECTORY_SEARCH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DREAM_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_INCALL_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_INTENT_FILTER_VERIFIER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_KEYGUARD_APPWIDGET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_MIDI_DEVICE_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_PACKAGE_VERIFIER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_PRINT_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_PRINT_SPOOLER_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_REMOTE_DISPLAY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ROUTE_PROVIDER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_TEXT_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_TRUST_AGENT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_TV_INPUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_VOICE_INTERACTION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_MAP"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_STACK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BRICK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_NETWORK_PRIVILEGED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA_DISABLE_TRANSMIT_LED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA_SEND_SYSTEM_EVENTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_HOTWORD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_TV_INPUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CARRIER_FILTER_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_APP_IDLE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_DEVICE_IDLE_TEMP_WHITELIST"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIMAX_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONFIGURE_WIFI_DISPLAY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONFIRM_FULL_BACKUP"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONNECTIVITY_INTERNAL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_INCALL_EXPERIENCE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_KEYGUARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_VPN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_WIFI_DISPLAY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.COPY_PROTECTED_DATA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CRYPT_KEEPER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DIAGNOSTIC"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISPATCH_NFC_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DUMP"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DVB_DEVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FACTORY_TEST"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FILTER_EVENTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_BACK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FRAME_STATS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FREEZE_SCREEN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS_PRIVILEGED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_APP_OPS_STATS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_DETAILED_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_IMPORTANCE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TOP_ACTIVITY_INFO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH_CONTROL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HDMI_CEC"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTENT_FILTER_VERIFICATION_AGENT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INVOKE_CARRIER_SETUP"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_UID"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LAUNCH_TRUST_AGENT_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOOP_RADIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACTIVITY_STACKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_APP_TOKENS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_CA_CERTIFICATES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_ADMINS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_FINGERPRINT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_MEDIA_PROJECTION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_NETWORK_POLICY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_PROFILE_AND_DEVICE_OWNERS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USB"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USERS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_VOICE_KEYPHRASES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MASTER_CLEAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_APPWIDGET_BIND_PERMISSIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_ROUTING"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_NETWORK_ACCOUNTING"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PARENTAL_CONTROLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOVE_PACKAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NET_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NET_TUNNELING"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC_HANDOVER_STATUS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NOTIFY_PENDING_SYSTEM_UPDATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.OBSERVE_GRANT_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.OEM_UNLOCK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.OVERRIDE_WIFI_CONFIG"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_VERIFICATION_AGENT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PEERS_MAC_ADDRESS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERFORM_CDMA_PROVISIONING"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERFORM_SIM_ACTIVATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERSISTENT_ACTIVITY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROVIDE_TRUST_AGENT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_DO_NOT_ASK_CREDENTIALS_ON_BOOT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CELL_BROADCASTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_DREAM_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INPUT_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INSTALL_SESSIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_NETWORK_USAGE_HISTORY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRECISE_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SEARCH_INDEXABLES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SOCIAL_STREAM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_VOICEMAIL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_WIFI_CREDENTIAL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BLUETOOTH_MAP"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_EMERGENCY_BROADCAST"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_STK_COMMANDS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WIFI_CREDENTIAL_CHANGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECOVERY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REGISTER_CALL_PROVIDER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REGISTER_CONNECTION_MANAGER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REGISTER_SIM_SUBSCRIPTION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REMOTE_AUDIO_PLAYBACK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REMOVE_DRM_CERTIFICATES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REMOVE_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RETRIEVE_WINDOW_CONTENT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RETRIEVE_WINDOW_TOKEN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REVOKE_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCORE_NETWORKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SERIAL_PORT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALWAYS_FINISH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_INPUT_CALIBRATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_KEYBOARD_LAYOUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ORIENTATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_POINTER_SPEED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_SCREEN_COMPATIBILITY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SHUTDOWN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SIGNAL_PERSISTENT_PROCESSES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.START_ANY_ACTIVITY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.START_TASKS_FROM_RECENTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STOP_APP_SWITCHES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.TEMPORARY_ENABLE_ACCESSIBILITY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.TRANSMIT_IR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.TRUST_LISTENER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.TV_INPUT_HARDWARE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_APP_OPS_STATS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_CONFIG"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USER_ACTIVITY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_DREAM_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can generate full list of permissions from \framework\base\core\res\AndroidManifest.xml (Android source code).
Here is full list for SDK 17.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS_NO_CONFIRMATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_EMERGENCY_BROADCAST" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CELL_BROADCASTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DIRECTORY_SEARCH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SOCIAL_STREAM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SOCIAL_STREAM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.voicemail.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIMAX_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIMAX_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_STACK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONNECTIVITY_INTERNAL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USB" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MTP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NET_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REMOTE_AUDIO_PLAYBACK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USERS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_DETAILED_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REMOVE_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.START_ANY_ACTIVITY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_SCREEN_COMPATIBILITY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_SCREEN_COMPATIBILITY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RETRIEVE_WINDOW_CONTENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERSISTENT_ACTIVITY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ASEC_ACCESS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ASEC_CREATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ASEC_DESTROY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ASEC_MOUNT_UNMOUNT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ASEC_RENAME" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_READ" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_WRITE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ALLOW_ANY_CODEC_FOR_PLAYBACK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DUMP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALWAYS_FINISH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SIGNAL_PERSISTENT_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DIAGNOSTIC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_BACK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_APP_TOKENS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FREEZE_SCREEN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FILTER_EVENTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RETRIEVE_WINDOW_INFO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.TEMPORARY_ENABLE_ACCESSIBILITY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MAGNIFY_DISPLAY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SHUTDOWN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STOP_APP_SWITCHES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INPUT_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_TEXT_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ORIENTATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_POINTER_SPEED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_KEYBOARD_LAYOUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOVE_PACKAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GRANT_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONFIGURE_WIFI_DISPLAY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_WIFI_DISPLAY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BRICK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NET_TUNNELING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FACTORY_TEST" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MASTER_CLEAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERFORM_CDMA_PROVISIONING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BACKUP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONFIRM_FULL_BACKUP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_KEYGUARD_APPWIDGET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_APPWIDGET_BIND_PERMISSIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH_CONTROL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_DREAM_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_DREAM_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.COPY_PROTECTED_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CRYPT_KEEPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_NETWORK_USAGE_HISTORY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_NETWORK_POLICY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_NETWORK_ACCOUNTING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.intent.category.MASTER_CLEAR.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_VERIFICATION_AGENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_PACKAGE_VERIFIER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SERIAL_PORT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CONTENT_PROVIDERS_EXTERNALLY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_LOCK" />
```

Warning: you will have to set ProtectedPermission to ignored in lint config to build it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to print all permissions:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(" \n");
    final Field[] manifestFields = Manifest.permission.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (final Field field : manifestFields) {
        sb.append("<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission."
                + field.getName() + "\"/>");
        sb.append("\n");
        if (sb.length() > 1000) {
            Log.v(TAG, sb.toString());
            sb = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

all Answer above are correct but one thing to remember we add permission in menifist..
as shown below

```
<manifest>

////////// all permission will be added here
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package="com.myapp" >
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Request you to describe your code how it solves the problem of OP. Code without explanation can be marked as low quality answer.